# Wireless mouse not working after last update

Tags: usb, mouse

Hello and thank you for your help.

Today I have updated Ubuntu and my wireless mouse has stopped working at all on USB 2.0 port.

From sudo dmesg I get this output when I connect My wireless mouse:

```
> [ 1713.945599] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 24 using
> xhci_hcd [ 1714.081371] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
> [ 1714.321364] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71 [
> 1714.561437] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 25 using xhci_hcd [ 1714.689710] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71
> [ 1714.925383] usb 1-4: device descriptor read/64, error -71 [
> 1715.037653] usb usb1-port4: attempt power cycle [ 1715.457274] usb 1-4: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd [ 1715.457395]
> usb 1-4: Device not responding to setup address. [ 1715.665359] usb
> 1-4: Device not responding to setup address. [ 1715.873266] usb 1-4:
> device not accepting address 26, error -71 [ 1716.001266] usb 1-4: new
> full-speed USB device number 27 using xhci_hcd [ 1716.001417] usb 1-4:
> Device not responding to setup address. [ 1716.209376] usb 1-4: Device
> not responding to setup address. [ 1716.417231] usb 1-4: device not
> accepting address 27, error -71 [ 1716.417329] usb usb1-port4: unable
> to enumerate USB device
```

Mouse is connected to an USB 2.0 port. If I unplug it and I connect it to an USB 3 port it runs perfectly.

Thanks in advance for your time.

---

The problem was a bad wire connection. USB port has a problem and is not easy to connect a device.

Thanks for your attention.